# Как дополнить функционал админки Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть две модели: User и Model. В модели Model есть привязка по ключу к пользователю. Нужно добавит в админку такой функционал - выбираем количество элементов и рандомно вынимаем из из Model, при этом дополняя данными из User и сохраняя в xlsx. С сохранением в эксель в целом всё понятно, но как реализовать это всё в админке, либо же прийдется создавать отдельную вьюшку??

Comment: Админка позволяет создавать вьюшки внутри себя https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

Comment: а как мне добавить графический интерфейс